# Apache rewrite custom http header to REMOTE_USER variable

Tags: apache-httpd

I have an application IBM WebSEAL which acts as a WAM for all our web servers. When I'm authenticated in Active Directory and access a WebSEAL enable resource WebSEAL gets my user-ID from the kerberos ticket and sets my Windows NT ID in a `iv-user` header in the http request. I'd like to configure now SSO for my application and its reading the `REMOTE_USER` Apache variable. My question is. How could I take `iv-user`and re-write it to `REMOTE_USER`? Any hints are highly appreciated! 
PS. I can confirm that Apache can see the `iv-user` variable.

EDIT:

Virtual Host configuration:

```
[root@otrs conf]# httpd -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS

VirtualHost configuration:
*:443                  otrs-1-lab.local.dom. com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:56)




[root@otrs conf]# less /etc/httpd/conf.d/zzz_otrs.conf

<IfModule mod_perl.c>

    # Setup environment and preload modules
    Perlrequire /opt/otrs/scripts/apache2-perl-startup.pl

    # Reload Perl modules when changed on disk
    PerlModule Apache2::Reload
    PerlInitHandler Apache2::Reload

    # general mod_perl2 options
    <Location /otrs>
#        ErrorDocument 403 /otrs/customer.pl
        ErrorDocument 403 /otrs/index.pl
        SetHandler  perl-script
        PerlResponseHandler ModPerl::Registry
        Options +ExecCGI
        PerlOptions +ParseHeaders
        PerlOptions +SetupEnv

        <IfModule mod_version.c>
            <IfVersion < 2.4>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
            </IfVersion>
            <IfVersion >= 2.4>
                Require all granted
            </IfVersion>
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule !mod_version.c>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </IfModule>
    </Location>

    # mod_perl2 options for GenericInterface
    <Location /otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl>
        PerlOptions -ParseHeaders
    </Location>

</IfModule>

<Directory "/opt/otrs/bin/cgi-bin/">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -Includes

    <IfModule mod_version.c>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all granted
        </IfVersion>
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_version.c>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apache [mod_setenvif](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_setenvif.html) will definetly will do work for you. I'd try something like:

```
SetEnvIf iv-user "(.*)$" REMOTE_USER=$1
```

If this will not work, there is also `SetEnvIfExpr` directive you can play with.

Comment: thank you! very would I have to include that line ?

Comment: in your definition of vhost in apache. between your `<VirtualHost>`and`</VirtualHost>`, or `<NameVirtualHost>` and `</NameVirtualHost>` tags

Comment: Do I have to setup another SSO like via mod_auth_kerb to set the REMOTE_USER variable or is it enough to re-write it ?

Comment: To rewrite headers - no. mod_auth_kerb is differrent story, then only headers.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help! I really appreciate it! Could you kindly help me with last more question. So I don’t have basically any VH other than the one that is getting created with mod_ssl. The problem is (if it is ) that I’d like to implement this rewriting condition (yes it works THANK YOU!) for x.x.x.x/otrs/index.pl (should I also add the rewrite under <Directory "/opt/otrs/bin/cgi-bin/">
In this case? I don’t want it for <Location /otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl> because that’s the API web service. Are my assumptions ok ? THANK YOU!

Comment: documentation (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) says, that you can use this option inside: `server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess`, so feel free to put it into the directory if you need to.

Comment: Thank you Alexander but I think I might have not well described my problem. The application hast 3 interfaces so to say. x.x.x.x/otrs/index.pl x.x.x.x/otrs/customer.pl and x.x.x.x/otrs/nph-genericinterface.pl I have put the line into httpd.conf SetEnvIf iv-user "(.*)$" REMOTE_USER=$1  . How would I apply the rule only to x.x.x.x/otrs/index.pl?

Comment: have you tried to put it depend on location `<Location x.x.x.x/otrs/index.pl> SetEnvIf iv-user "(.*)$" REMOTE_USER=$1</Location>`

Comment: Yes but then it is not working even after restarting httpd.

Comment: should work. check your location twice. Remember that it starts from the slash and doesn't contain host. So for e.g. `https://example.com/location/test.cgi` Location would be `<Location /location/test.cgi>`

Comment: it only works when I add it either to httpd.conf or the /etc/httpd/conf.d/zzz_otrs.conf under `<Directory "/opt/otrs/bin/cgi-bin/">
    SetEnvIf HTTP_IV_USER "(.*)$" REMOTE_USER=$1
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -Includes`